# add an image to a product with Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to obtain the value of an image that is uploaded to an input and after clicking on add product that is shown together with the added product, I have tried a lot and I can not, this is my code.

[I've tried a lot and couldn't get any results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JMR2x.jpg)

[image]

```
const price = document.getElementById("price").value    

const img = document.getElementById("file");
```

My another code

```
 <div class="card">
            <div class="card-body">
            <div id="file" class="img-product">${product.img}</div>
            <h3>${product.name}</h3>
                <p id="product-description">${product.description}</p>
                <p>Precio: <b>${product.price}</b> RD$ </p>
                <button id="buy-product" class="btn btnprimary">Comprar
                </button>
                <button id="add-product" class="btn btn-warning">Add+</button>
            </div>
        </div>
```

My HTML code :

```
<form id="form-products" class="row">
  <div class="col-md-4">
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="product-name" 
  placeholder="Nombre..">
   <input class="form-control my-2" type="file" id="file"  accept="image/*" 
     placeholder="imagen">   
 </div>
<div class="col-md-4">
   <textarea id="description" cols="10" rows="1" class="form-control" 
     placeholder="Descripcion"></textarea>
     <input type="submit" value="Add product" class="btn btn-warning my-2">  
</div>
   <div class="col-md-4">
     <input id="price" type="number" class="form-control" 
      placeholder="Precio">
</div>
</form>
```

**everything works fine except the image**

Comment: `<form id="form-products" class="row">
<div> 
<input class="form-control my-2" type="file" id="file"  accept="image/*" placeholder="imagen">   
   </div>                       
<div class="col-md-4">
<input id="price" type="number" class="form-control" placeholder="Precio">
</div>                      
</form>`   this is mi html code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well I have tried this on my machine and it works fine!!,

My HTML CODE

```
<html>
<head>
    <title> Image </title>
    <script src="./index.js" defer></script>
</head>
<body>
    <button class="btn"> Add Image </button>
    <img id="image">
</body>
</html>
```

My JS Code

```
document.querySelector(".btn").addEventListener("click", () => {
  const path = "./img/Screenshot (1).png";
  const img = document.querySelector("#image");
  img.src = path;
});
```

Answer (score 2):

`document.getElementById('file')` will only give you the `<input>` element, not its contents. Have you tried accessing its value like you do with the price?

Answer (score 1):

use this

```
const img = document.getElementById("file")
img.src = "pathToYourFile"
```

Comment: I tried it but it still says undefined and in the console no value appears, what I want is for the image to be added together with the product data when I give  to add